# Sharepoint 2010 Document Organizational Structure

Tags: search, managed-metadata, content-and-structure

Our company wants to rollout a knowledge base site which will contain most of the company’s documentation. As any good SharePoint Admin would do, I am using managed metadata keywords and terms to tag all the documents. With that said, how would I break down a previous multi-level folder structure such as this:

Client --> Client ID --> Department --> Special Areas --> Documents

On the site home page I have created a link for each client site as well as a tag navigation web part similar to a folder hierarchy, but from there I am having a hard time putting together the most efficient way to break down these tiers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you not use a term set with the same hierarchy? Then use Keyword Navigation and it's just like the tree view in a file share.

Comment: I have the keyword navigation connected to a search core results web part which works well, but I'm not sure if tags have the ability to search within a specific hierarchy. For example is I tagged a document under client 1-->clientID 1-->dept 1-->doc 1, when a user searches the "doc 1" tag will it show the doc 1 under client-- clientID 1-- dept 1 or will it show all doc 1 tagged under any client? Does that make sense?

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it. I'd think that all "doc 1" result will be shown and the search refiners on the left can be used to drill down.

Answer (score 0):

The search result refiners will contain the metadata fields, which can then be used to drill down into the search results.